# liferay 6.2 to liferay 7 Calendar API migrated to OSGi

Tags: liferay, osgi, liferay-7

i have liferay 6.2 GA4, and im trying to migrate to liferay 7
im using the code upgrade tool

the error im getting is Calendar's API migrated to OSGi

but i cant find how to do this, how do i change the portlet to OSGi? how do i import the calendar module to my portlet? the upgrade tool only says "#Legacy" in the documentation change, so i dont know what to do next... i have a lot of this "#Legacy" errors, how do i correct them?

this question is a duplicate from the liferay forums, but i havent got an answer yet

**edit**

i dont know the best way to migrate, but i do have a portlet (many portlets actually), i want to use it (them) in a liferay 7 instalation... the portlet im trying to migrate first (the simpler one) uses the calendar API of liferay 6.2 im guessing i just have to add the calendar module, so i can use its classes, i just dont know how... i use calendar API in both the controller and the jsps

the text in the migration tool only says "#Legacy"... that it! thats why im so confused... in eclipse the error says "Calendar API migrated to OSGi" and thats it too... thats why i imagine i just need to add the calendar module...

thank you!

Comment: This is not something I have experience with, but I know there's some documentation on upgrading using the Code Upgrade tool. Have you read through it? There's actually a bunch of docs on moving plugins from Liferay Portal 6 to 7. https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/adapting-to-liferay-7s-api-with-the-code-upgrade-tool

Comment: yes i have, thats the documentatio im following...

Comment: Perhaps if you provide more details, someone can provide an answer more easily. For example, it looks like you have a portlet, right? Are you trying to migrate it all the way to an OSGi module packaged as a JAR? Is it a Service Builder portlet? With the information you've given, it's hard for me to understand your context. [Not sure I can help either way but maybe we can draw attention to your issue]

Comment: thank you i edited my post with more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it! you just have to add the Calendar api to the gradle configurations

```
classpath group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.calendar.api", version: "2.0.2"
classpath group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.calendar.service", version: "2.1.9"
```

in the settings.gradle's dependencys section

and this:

```
compileOnly group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.calendar.api", version: "2.0.2"
compileOnly group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.calendar.service", version: "2.1.9"
```

in the build.gradle of your portlet!

and that works!

thank you

Answer (score 1):

What is the text from the error/change message?

Regarding "Calendar API", is it that you want to use the Calendar API from Liferay's Calendar app?

Note, you should first get your existing portlet running on 7.0 before modularizing it. The updated tutorial *Planning Plugin Upgrades and Optimizations* has a table of Upgrade Paths for each plugin type and feature.

Jim

Comment: thank you, i edited my post... and yes i just want it running, not even tinking ahead (like modularizing it).. .and yes, i use the calendar API from liferay's calendar app...